# Let's encourage the commenter with the correct answer to post it as an answer

Tags: discussion

It's been a while in Stack Overflow, and I have seen so many times that an actual answer was provided as a comment to the question. Later, I see a list of answers repeating the same thing.

Yes, I know, usually the comment is voted up, however, the poster who actually commented with the perfect answer, ethically waits for OP's reply. And then, what we see is a series of answers on the basis of the previous comments.

The poster providing the correct answer through comment, should be encouraged to post it as an answer when majority of us think so.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? That someone who *chose* to use a comment rather than an answer should not be surprised if someone else posts an actual answer and gets upvotes?

Comment: @MartijnPieters <3 the irony of posting a comment as answer to this question.  I'm kinda regretting posting an actual answer now.

Comment: @Servy: Hey, I *made a choice* to post a comment. Mostly because I am also asking for clarification, I suppose.

Comment: The person commenting first rather than posting an answer, usually thinks twice and waits for OP's clarification.

Comment: When you think a comment should be an answer, then *ask the commenter to post an answer*. Just with a comment. Simple, low tech.

Comment: I am just pressing the fact that we could suggest the commenter to post it as an answer. It never happened with me, just saying on behalf of them. To encourage you all to do so.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: What is the actual question here?

Comment: I expect you're getting downvotes because this issue has been discussed here many times and a cursory search would have led you to some of those discussions.

Comment: Please don't abuse backticks. Also "improvise the question"? Do you mean "improve"?

Comment: _Google search didn't suffice_ [Worked for me](https://www.google.com/#q=site:meta.stackexchange.com+answers+in+comments). Maybe you need to work on your Google Fu.

Comment: @the Ice, Google search results are NOT same across the different geographic locations. And there are many other factors,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't post an answer as a comment.  Answers should be posted as answers.

Comment: Alternately, you're free to do so but don't be surprised if someone else does the work for you and gets the credit.

Comment: Ok fine. So the person answering first with his own aim(perhaps to gain some points) is better than a technically sound person who waits for OP to clarify his requirements.

Comment: @LalitKumarB You very explicitly specified an *answer* posted as a comment.  Not a clarifying question requiring a response.

Comment: Sorry folks, but I updated my question title. Do you all still think it to be absurd?

Comment: @LalitKumarB If they want to post their comment as an answer, they can.  If they don't, they don't have to.  It's *entirely* up to them.  There is a built in incentive to post answers as answers in that answers can be voted on.

Comment: @Servy, et al. Please see my updated question title. I am sorry if I wasn't clear about it.